# How do you store a value of grep into an array and then print array?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sed, grep

```
z=0
for i in "${ofield[@]}"; do
  temp=$(grep '#include "' ${cppfield[z]} | sed s/#include// | sed s/\"//g)
  echo "${ofield[$i]} : ${cppfield[$i]} ${temp[@]}" >> Makefile
  echo "    g++ -ansi -Wall -g -c ${cppfield[i]}" >> Makefile
  ((z++))
done
```

I am attempting to loop through an array of .cpp files and an array of .o files to print each component of the .o array, then the .cpp array, followed by the grepping of the .cpp array for header files.
I keep getting the error "invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")

Comment: `temp=$(....)` does not create an array. It creates a string.

Comment: Have you seen http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ ?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of the script and you'll see the commands as they execute.

Comment: Agree with Etan: You seems to try to create dependency lists (included header files) of .cpp files.. Please try auto-dependency as suggested by Etan, or post your real problem/application to be solved, rather than asking to correct your solution.  You might have gone to the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

1st: `man bash`

2nd: `i` seems to be not numeric, contains strings of object files, so you cannot use `i` for indexing in `${cppfield[i]}`, use `${i}` itself as filename

3rd: `temp=$(...)` does not create an array, use `($(...))`, watch out for spaces in your filenames, update your `IFS=$'\n'`

4th: addressing elements in array using an index `z` should look like `array[${z}]` if z is numeric and if it is not an associative array